# SQL rows are not being deleted

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, sql-server, sql-delete

So I have this code that is designed to delete a row in mySQL server database judging by what is selected in my list box. Here is the code I have to remove the rows:

```
private void remove_btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            if (Calls_lsb.SelectedItem == null)

                MessageBox.Show("Please select an item for deletion.");
            }
            else
            {
                int i = Calls_lsb.SelectedIndex;
                if (i > 0)
                {
                    SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(//My Connection String);
                    string sqlStatement1 = "DELETE FROM Records WHERE CallID = @Id";
                    string sqlStatement2 = "DELETE FROM Calls WHERE CallID = @Id";

                    connection.Open();
                    SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand(sqlStatement1, connection);
                    cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id", Calls_lsb.Items[i]);
                    cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand(sqlStatement2, connection);
                    cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id", Calls_lsb.Items[i]);
                    cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    connection.Close();

                    Calls_lsb.Items.Remove(Calls_lsb.Items[i]);
                }
                else
                {
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
        }
    }
```

I get no exceptions and I have similar code that adds records that works fine. I tried stepping into the code but it all seemed fine. It simply just does not delete the row from the database. It removes the correct item from the list, just not the database.

If anyone could shine some light on this situation that would be great, thanks!

Edit : Ok, I seem to have fixed the problem. I just removed the whole i = selected index stuff and replace the 'Calls_lsb.Items[i]' with '(Calls_lsb.SelectedIndex + 1)'. I don't really understand why I was getting an exception when I tried to add 1 to i as this is basically doing the same thing.

Comment: What is the value of `Calls_lsb.Items[i]` exactly ? Are you sure your connection string is right? Did you try your `DELETE` statement in your sql server management studio? Is it works in it?

Comment: Good point, I just tested the query on sql and it worked. I stepped through again and it seems that i is 0 which is does not correlate to my CallID which is 1. I messed around a little trying to add 1 to the index but I get an ArgumentOutOfRangeException saying that the argument value of '1' is not value for index. Any ideas?

Comment: How many items are in Calls_lsb.Items? If you have only 1 item this will have an index of 0 as it's 0 based.

Comment: Also, if 0 isn't a valid CallID then presumably you have a default item at index 0 e.g. "Please Select Item" or something? If that's the case then the index 0 should be added to your first part of your if statement like if (Calls_lsb.SelectedItem == null || Calls_lsb.SelectedIndex == 0)

Comment: Thanks for the help guys but I solved the problem. Thanks for the validation suggestion also , although I don't think it will be needed with my solution

Comment: When you try and add 1 to i were you doing 'Calls_lsb.Items[i+1]'? If so this means you're looking for the item at index 1, which there won't be if there is only 1 item. This will be of index 0. Index of 1 won't exist. However, when you do 'Calls_lsb.SelectedIndex + 1 you are simply getting the index as int and adding 1 to it, which will give you 0 + 1 (with 1 item).

Comment: I tried several different methods, Calls_lsb.Items[i+1], int i = Calls_lsb.SelectedIndex + 1, i++. Thanks for the information :)

Answer (score 0):

Replace your below line code.

```
  cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id", Calls_lsb.Items[i]);
  //with 
  cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id", Calls_lsb.Items[i].Value);
```

and

```
  cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id", Calls_lsb.Items[i]);
```

// with

```
  cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id", Calls_lsb.Items[i].Value);
```

Comment: Adding a '.Value' gives me an error and isn't part of my intellisense: ''object' does not contain a definition for 'Value''.

Comment: Could you please help me out to understand "Calls_lsb.Items[i]" what is the Calls_lsb, I guess it is object of DropDownList ?? correct?

Comment: Calls_lsb.Items[i] is the selected item index in my list box.

Comment: Hey Simon if Calls_lsb is a object of ListBox then there should be  a Value and Text property with Items, so please confirm the Calls_lsb is an object of ListBox class.

Comment: Calls_lsb is the name of my listbox. .Items is the items that exist within the listbox.